# Correct syntax for hyperlink URL with PHP $_GET

Tags: php, html, url, get, href

I am wondering how I would put information from my website in the URL on the first page of my site, and then on the next page, use `$_GET` to get the variables from the URL.

I was just wanting to put it in a link like `<a href="mywebsite.com/page?name=$name"></a>` So would it work if I did it like that, and if it would, how would I get it from the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/page?name=<?php echo $name; ?>"></a>
```

And in your page, you could get the name as:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: Ok thanks it worked Ill accept it when the 15 minutes has passed

Comment: You need an http:// in front of that link...else it'll try to open http://example.com/mywebsite.com/page?name=something.

Answer (score 5):

Example Link: `http://example.com/page.php?name=Charles`

If you used `$_GET["name"]` it would return the value `Charles`

For more information on $_GET look at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1):

the `$_GET` is the variable. so in this case, to get the name, it would be:

```
$_GET['name'];
```

Comment: no, so for example if you go to http://example.com?name=test , on that page, $_GET['name'] will be "test"